# Android video filter

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, filter

I'm trying to create an app where I am able to add filters to a recorded video. Basically, I want to replicate the functionality that exists in Instagram video, or Viddy.

I've done research and I can't piece it all together. I've looked into using GLSurfaceView to play the recorded video and I know I could use NDK to do the pixel manipulation and send it back to the SurfaceView or save it somehow. The problem is, I don't know how to send the pixel data because there seems to be no function to access it. This idea came from the Camera function "onPreviewFrame". The function returns a byte array allowing me to manipulate the pixels and display it.

Another idea is to use GLSurfaceView and use OpenGL to render the filter. GLSurfaceView has a renderer you can set, but I'm not very familiar with OpenGL. But again, this goes back to actually getting the pixels of each video frame. I also read about ripping each frame as a texture and then manipulating the texture in OpenGL but the answers I've come across are not very detailed.

Lastly, I've looked into JavaCV. Trying to use FFmpegFrameGrabber, but I haven't had much either. I wanted to just grab one frame, but when I try to write the frame's ByteBuffer to an ImageView, I get a "buffer not large enough for pixels" error.

Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 7):

From Android 4.3 you can use a `Surface` as the input to your encoder. http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#Multimedia

So you can use GLSurfaceView and apply the filters using fragment shaders.

You can find some good examples here. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Comment: In particular, DecodeEditEncodeTest is a CTS test that exercises decoding a video, modifying it with a GLES shader, and re-encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to use the exoplayer filter library and this one will do your work but in order to merge the filtered layered with the video you have to do an extra work.

Link for exoplayer filter is there for you : [ExoplayerFilter](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/ExoPlayerFilter)

You have to se the exoplayer for this but follow their instructions you'll be able to do  the task. Ping me if something comes up.