# How to use Video Filter at real time in Android?

Tags: android

i want to apply some effects to real video which taken by camera.By browsing through some links i found that it could be achieved by using video filter libraries. can anyone suggest any such libraries that fit  in my case?
the same kind of question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730080/android-video-filter)  and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725877/android-video-color-filter).however there is no response for them.

Comment: Please do not create duplicate questions for what is already asked.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). There are some [example demos](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=opencv&c=apps) using OpenCV on Android. I believe you should be able to build some video filters with OpenCV.

Also, take a look at some of the Augmented Reality libraries, they contain some of the same mechanisms that video filters have as well.