# How to merge mp4 video with colored layer in Android?

Tags: android, video, merge, layer, mp4parser

I have requirement to show Video with different filters should apply on it
each filter is a colored layer

How to merge video with Colored layer above it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730080/android-video-filter ?